# trigger onclick on page load given url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

how can i trigger an onclick event on a page such as this which would open an even modal:

http://rikdevos.com/demos/wordpress-responsive-timetable/demo-1/]demo[1](http://rikdevos.com/demos/wordpress-responsive-timetable/demo-1/)

via a url on another page? a jsfiddle example would be helpful.

this is a jquery-enabled site.

perhaps something like this?
give anchor some hash and string, then when page withe vents loads, a script runs which detects given string and fires relevant onclick?

as far as being potentially similar to another question: seems like it only focuses on clicking the link, and not reading a url hash string as well in order to determine which onclick to trigger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically click on a link using jQuery on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041161/programmatically-click-on-a-link-using-jquery-on-page-load)

Comment: seems like it only focuses on clicking the link, and not reading a url hash string as well in order to determine which onclick to trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can just ask the browser for the current URL and split it to get its parameter. Something like:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var splitUrl = currentUrl.split('/');
// Last element of the split URL array is the parameter you want
var urlParam = splitUrl[splitUrl.length-1];
$('#'+urlParam).click();
```